# Producto de lo elementos de una fila

Tags: python

podria por favor ayudarme a calcular el producto de los elementos de una fila que es elegida por el usuario. Este es el ejercicio:
Construir un programa que cree una matriz de tamaño MxN, llenarla con números aleatorios y calcular el producto de los elementos de la fila seleccionada por el usuario.

```
matriz=[]

filas=int(input("cantidad de filas: "))
columnas= int(input("cantidad de columnas: "))

for i in range(filas):
    matriz.append([0]*columnas)
for f in range(filas):
    for g in range(columnas):
        matriz[f][g]= int(input("elemento ( %d, %d ): " % (f,g)))
print(matriz)

n=int(input("ingrese la fila a calcular: "))
producto=[]

for i in range (filas):
    producto.append(matriz[n][i])
    print(producto)

for i in range(len(producto)):
    print(i*producto)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden.

Comment: Si dices que eso es **PHP** estás un poco perdid@. En cuanto sepas en que lenguaje estás programando podrías actualizar la etiqueta de la pregunta para que se te pueda ayudar más fácilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Valeria, bienvenida. Modifiqué un poco tú código, agregando lo siguiente:

En primer lugar, uso `randint(1, 10)` del modulo **random**, permite generar enteros aleatorios dentro de un rango, en este caso, de uno a diez.

Luego, recorro los elementos de la matriz en la fila seleccionada, acumulando el resultado de la multiplicación en la variable **producto** `producto *= valor`.

Finalmente el **print** incorpora `{}` para usar `format`, pasándole como parámetros, la lista y el producto final.

```
from random import randint

matriz = []
filas = int(input("cantidad de filas: "))
columnas = int(input("cantidad de columnas: "))

for i in range(filas):
    matriz.append([0]*columnas)
for f in range(filas):
    for g in range(columnas):
        matriz[f][g] = randint(1, 10)
print(matriz)

n = int(input("Ingrese la fila a calcular: "))
producto = 1

for valor in matriz[n-1]:
  producto *= valor

print("El producto de la matriz {}, es {}.".format(matriz[n-1], producto))
```

Si no es lo que esperabas o tienes alguna duda, por favor deja un comentario.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

matriz = []
filas = int(input("cantidad de filas: "))
columnas = int(input("cantidad de columnas: "))

for i in range(filas):
    matriz.append([0]*columnas)
for f in range(filas):
    for g in range(columnas):
        matriz[f][g] = randint(1, 10)
print(matriz)

n = int(input("Ingrese la fila a calcular: "))
producto = 1

for valor in matriz[n-1]:
  producto *= valor

print("El producto de la matriz {}, es {}.".format(matriz[n-1], producto))
```

Comment: Para una mejor calidad en la respuesta, se recomienda que se explique el código que se agregue, así para facilitar al usuario entender en qué fallo.